# Помогите новичку с аргументами *args в Python/Питон, пожалуйта!

Tags: python

Нужно, чтобы условный пользователь вводил числа, а потом получал их сумму. Я пробовал так:

```
def summa(*args):
    print(sum(args))
summa(list(map(int, input('Введите через пробел числа для исчесления суммы: ').split())))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Но пишет, что эти типы не поддерживаются. Пробовал и через list, и через tuple, и через int, и через float - ничего. Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Или добавьте звёздочку перед `list(` или наоборот удалите звёздочку перед `*args`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так примерно должен выглядеть ваш код

```
def summa(*args):

    print(sum(args))
    summa(*list(map(int, input('Введите через пробел числа для исчесления суммы: ').split())))

summa()
```